# jqPlot hidden div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have a bunch of divs that are initially hidden, and I attempt to draw a plot within those hidden divs. I've realized that you can't draw within a hidden div, so what I've done is that when the user clicks the button to display the div, I replot the graph(along with drawing it when it's hidden, but I receive this message in Google Chrome's Developer Tools "Uncaught Error: Target dimension not set" and the plot does not display.

Here is the code I use to plot the charts while it's hidden, jqPlots is an array which contains the variables used for plotting.

```
var plot = $.jqplot (DATA GOES IN HERE)
    jqPlots.push(plot)
```

Then within the handler for displaying the div I have

```
for(var i = 0; i<jqPlots.length; i++)
{   
    jqPlots[i].replot();
}
```

Comment: How are you hiding the DIV? A visibility:hidden element can still have dimensions, display:none has, well, none.

Comment: @roblarsen I'm using display:none, I'll try it out with visibility:hidden.

Comment: @roblarsen Hmm, now I see the outline of my plots as well as the legend, but I don't see any data within the charts, could there be any reason for this?

Comment: I don't know much about jqplot in specific, so I can't help there. Sorry

Comment: this link would answer your question:

 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294807/jqplot-enlarging-the-chart-and-using-replot-function/19299612#19299612][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294807/jqplot-enlarging-the-chart-and-using-replot-function/19299612#19299612