# jqPlot replot only shows legend, no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am attempting to replot a chart when the user selects the tab to display the chart(initially it is set to visibility:hidden). Once it plots the graphs again, I don't see any of the lines or bars in the graphs, I only see the legend. I want to see all of the data again. When I don't hide the element and just plot it, it works fine, but I need to hide the element so that data can be grouped together in a logical order.

Here is the code I use to plot the charts while it's hidden, jqPlots is an array which contains the variables used for plotting.

```
var plot = $.jqplot (DATA GOES IN HERE)
    jqPlots.push(plot)
```

Then within the handler for displaying the div I have

```
for(var i = 0; i<jqPlots.length; i++)
{   
    jqPlots[i].replot();
}
```

Comment: this would answer your question:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294807/jqplot-enlarging-the-chart-and-using-replot-function/19299612#19299612](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294807/jqplot-enlarging-the-chart-and-using-replot-function/19299612#19299612)

Comment: @Gyandeep, do you have any idea why everything but the lines/bars and background for the image is not being displayed in my case?